# NetUSerSetInfo does not set UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED

Tags: windows

I'm trying to write an application that is supposed to force a user to change his/her password at next logon. So I have tried to use NetUserSetInfo with structures 1001, 1008, or 1017, on flag UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED (for 1001 and 1008), and the current epoch (for 1017). I also tried to combine 1008 and 1017. Knowing that I have tested my application from the Administrator account.

I also tried to call NetUserSetInfo with the computer name NULL, "." and "MyComputer" (I found a post saying that it works with). With NULL the return error code is 0. With "." it is ERROR_IO_PENDING, and with"MyComputer"it is "invalid name".

But all the experiments give the same result. I.e. the flag is not set.

I found a post saying that the flag UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED is for XP only. But it is not compliant with the Windows documentation. And this flag is set if I check "user must change password at next logon" from the control panel.

So how to set this flag programmatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the documentation for the Network Management API does not always clearly state whether the state of any particular flag can be changed or is read-only, but I've done some testing, and it looks as if the `UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED` flag is one of the read-only ones.

The correct way to force a password reset is using `usri4_password_expired`,

> When you call NetUserAdd or NetUserSetInfo, specify a nonzero value in this member to inform users that they must change their password at the next logon.

This worked for me:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <LM.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t ** argv)
{
    // argv[1] must contain the username

    DWORD err;
    USER_INFO_4 *ui4;

    err = NetUserGetInfo(NULL, argv[1], 4, (LPBYTE*)(&ui4));
    if (err != 0)
    {
        printf("NetUserGetInfo: %u\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    ui4->usri4_password_expired = 1;

    err = NetUserSetInfo(NULL, argv[1], 4, (LPBYTE)ui4, NULL);
    if (err != 0)
    {
        printf("NetUserSetInfo: %u\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    NetApiBufferFree(ui4);

    printf("OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks a lot. I still have a problem. But it is probably a side effect of the previous tries I did. The fact that the same data are duplicated in numerus structures is also a problem. You never know which one will have the expected effect. And you cannot test all of them.